# Adjust axis limits on facet_share population pyarmid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-bar

I have created a population pyramid using geom_bar and facet_share. However, the data labels do not fit inside the panels with the current axis limits, or panel sizes.

I have tried forcing the panel size, but this just increases the size of everything in proportion.
I have also tried setting the ylim, but this increases the axis in both directions.

I would like there to be enough space in the facet panels for the data labels to be visible.

```r
#Here is the data

AgeGroupDat <-
structure(list(sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Male", "Female"), class = "factor"), Age_Group = c("00 - 20", "16 - 38",                                                                                         "18 - 34", "20 - 41", "32 - 54", "41 - 63", "48 - 69", "50 - 73",                                                                                                                                         "62 - 86", "76 - 98", "00 - 20", "16 - 38", "18 - 34", "20 - 41",                                                                                                                                  "32 - 54", "41 - 63", "48 - 69", "50 - 73", "62 - 86", "76 - 98"                                                                                 ), n = c(19318, 19050, 13948, 17416, 13893, 12495, 11038, 10813,                                                                                      4751, 612, -19915, -15443, -11091, -13599, -11969, -11525, -10442,                                                                                              -10119, -4124, -367)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df",                                                                                                                                                   "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```r
#And here is the plot

AgeGroupDat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Age_Group, y = n, fill = sex))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_text(data = subset(AgeGroupDat,
                          sex == "Female"),
            aes(label = abs(n)),
            hjust = -0.3,
            size = 3,
            #position = position_stack(vjust = -.01)
  )+ 
  geom_text(data = subset(AgeGroupDat,
                          sex == "Male"),
            aes(label = abs(n)),
            hjust = 1.2,
            size = 3,
            #position = position_stack()
  )+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_share(~sex, dir = "h", scales = "free", reverse_num = TRUE)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#9a0138","#000775"))+
    labs(title = "test")+
  labs(subtitle = "test")+
  labs(caption = "test")+
  labs(y = NULL)+
  labs(x = NULL)+
  labs(fill = "Member Sex")+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  ylim(-25000, 25000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to switch to the `ggh4x` package which via `facetted_pos_scales` allows to set the scales individually for each panel. Doing so however requires to manually remove the axis text for one of the `y` scales. Additionally, for nicely centered labels we have to remove the panel spacing via `panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt")` and set the same margin for the `y` axis text.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(AgeGroupDat, aes(y = Age_Group, x = n, fill = sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = abs(n), hjust = ifelse(sex == "Female", -.3, 1.3)),
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Female = "#9a0138", Male = "#000775"), drop = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~sex, scales = "free") +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(
      scale_x_continuous(
        labels = abs, expand = c(0, 2500, 0, 0),
        limits = c(-20000, 0)
      ),
      scale_x_continuous(
        expand = c(0, 0, 0, 2500),
        limits = c(0, 20000)
      )
    ),
    y = list(
      scale_y_discrete(position = "right"),
      scale_y_discrete(labels = NULL)
    )
  ) +
  labs(
    x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = "Member Sex",
    title = "test",
    subtitle = "test",
    caption = "test"
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(0, 2.2, 0, 2.2)),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent stefan! That's the answer in one go! I am learning more about ggh4x. It solves some questions that have been costing me a bunch of time. Thanks so much!

Comment: What can I do if all my labels do not have exactly the same length? How would I be able to center them in this case, since they are left aligned?

Comment: A possible workaround that just came into my mind would be to evenly distributed empty spaces before and after the label so that in total all labels have the same amount of characters (including empty spaces)? However, the labels would only be perfectly centered if the original labels are either all of even or of uneven length, right? Also I sometimes use an imported font, where not every character has the same width. In this case it would also not work, I guess.