# Use different axis limits in plot using ggpol's facet_share

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I want the the x axis (before using `coord_flip()` the y axis) in the following plot to start at one value (say at 20) for the left chart and at another value (say at 80) for the right chart. I tried using `ylim()` inside `coord_flip()` but that does not work for me since (1) in reality the left axis has negative values and (2) it would make the axis in both plots start at the same value.

I found this post where they use `geom_segment()` in combination with `scale_y_continuous` but I also don't know how to make this work for two plots with a shared axis.

[ggplot2 flipped y-axis bars not showing with correctly set limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504535/ggplot2-flipped-y-axis-bars-not-showing-with-correctly-set-limits)

This is my code:

```
librarian::shelf(ggpol, tidyverse)

dat <- 
  tibble(group = rep(letters[1:5], each = 2),
         type = factor(paste0("type", rep(c(1:2), 5))),
         value = c(-50, 110, -45, 120, -40, 130, -35, 140, -30, 150))

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_share(~type, scales = "free", reverse_num = TRUE)
```

Comment: For a related issue and an answer using the `ggh4x` package see [Adjust axis limits on facet_share population pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75088808/adjust-axis-limits-on-facet-share-population-pyarmid/75089376#75089376).

Comment: Thank you. That made it work. A small problem remains with this solution, however. Using ```facet_pos_scales``` I am not able to modify the axis labels on using for example ```scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(decimal.mark = ","))``` because it introduces NAs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the helpful comment from [stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan) pointing out the `ggh4x` package I was able to solve it:

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_share(~type, scales = "free", reverse_num = TRUE) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-40, -30)),
             scale_x_continuous(limits = c(35, 215))))
```

For some reason, however, I can't modify the axis labels of the left plot via for example `scal_x_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(decimal.mark = ","))`. I posted another question here:
[Modifying axis labels via scales::number() introduces NAs in combination with facetted_pos_scales()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75612725/modifying-axis-labels-via-scalesnumber-introduces-nas-in-combination-with-fa)