# Modifying axis labels via scales::number() introduces NAs in combination with facetted_pos_scales()

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, ggh4x

I have the following butterfly plot that works as expected thanks to the `ggh4x` package.

```
librarian::shelf(ggpol, tidyverse)

dat <- 
  tibble(group = rep(letters[1:5], each = 2),
         type = factor(paste0("type", rep(c(1:2), 5))),
         value = c(-50, 110, -45, 120, -40, 130, -35, 140, -30, 150))

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_share(~type, scales = "free", reverse_num = TRUE) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-40, -30)),
             scale_x_continuous(limits = c(35, 215))))
```

When I try to modify the left x axis labels via `labels = scales::label_number(decimal.mark = ",")` NAs are introduced.

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_share(~type, scales = "free", reverse_num = TRUE) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-40, -30),
                                labels = label_number(decimal.mark = ",")),
             scale_x_continuous(limits = c(35, 215))))
```

When I try the same for the right axis, the problem does not appear. (I use `label_percent()` because there are no decimal points in the right axis to change. But similarly `label_percent()` would not work on the left axis.

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_share(~type, scales = "free", reverse_num = TRUE) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-40, -30)),
             scale_x_continuous(limits = c(35, 215),
                                labels = label_percent())))
```

What is the problem here and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not related to `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` but due to setting `reverse_num=TRUE` which according to the docs

> will multiply the axis labels for that panel by -1.

Haven't had a closer look but would guess that this multiplication is done on the formatted labels and hence will result in the NAs.

To fix that set `reverse_num=FALSE` and transform the mnumerics before applying  the `scales::label_number`, e.g. by using `abs()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpol)
library(ggh4x)

dat <-
  tibble(
    group = rep(letters[1:5], each = 2),
    type = factor(paste0("type", rep(c(1:2), 5))),
    value = c(-50, 110, -45, 120, -40, 130, -35, 140, -30, 150)
  )

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = group)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_share(~type, scales = "free") +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(
      scale_x_continuous(
        limits = c(-40, -30),
        labels = ~scales::label_number(decimal.mark = ",")(abs(.x))
      ),
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(35, 215))
    )
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Another slightly related question: Using ```axis.ticks.y = element_blank()``` produces the following error: 

Error in axes$y$left[[1]]$children$axis$grobs[[lab_idx]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index.

I can circumvent this problem by using ```axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour = "white")``` but it would be interesting to know how to do this the correct way? Or should I open another question for this issue?

Comment: Don't have a clue how to fix that. Had a look and it's definitly a ggpol issue, i.e. we get the same issue when dropping facetted_posscales. IMHO ggpol isn't that well designed. That's why I stopped using it.

Comment: I found your post making a similar plot where you used ```facet_wrap()``` instead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75088808/adjust-axis-limits-on-facet-share-population-pyarmid/75089376#75089376). My problem with your version is that my plot does not look very nice, because my labels are not "a" to "e" (or like the age categories that you use with exactly the same length each) but labels of different length and I am not able to center them nicely between the two plots. Is that possible with ```facet_wrap()```?

Comment: I added a comment under your original post, it makes more sense there.